# How to output Array[String] to Json file?

Tags: sql, json, scala

I want to convert Array[String] to JSON File.
It looks like this:

```scala
scala> ok.foreach(println)
Bayern Munich,7
Borussia Dortmund,5
Arsenal,3
Schalke 04,2
SC Freiburg,1
Hannover 96,1
Lazio,1
Chelsea,1
Borussia Mönchengladbach,1
Real Madrid,1
```

I need these numbers to stay in place because their order is crucial.

I tried using:
ok.write.format("json").save("Query11.json")
but this is the error I get:
error: value write is not a member of Array[String]

Comment: do you want to write Array[String] or RDD or dataframe? `write.format("json")` is only available on dataframe

Comment: I want to write Array[String]. Is there something similar that would work for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scala> ok
res58: Array[String] = Array(Bayern Munich,7, Borussia Dortmund,5, Arsenal,3, Schalke 04,2, SC Freiburg,1, Hannover 96,1, Lazio,1, Chelsea,1, Borussia Mönchengladbach,1, Real Madrid,1)

scala> val df  =  sc.parallelize(ok).toDF("Arr_string")
scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"Arr_string", ",")).select(
     |   $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("Name"),
     |   $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("Number")
     | ).drop("_tmp")

scala> df1.show(false)
+------------------------+------+
|Name                    |Number|
+------------------------+------+
|Bayern Munich           |7     |
|Borussia Dortmund       |5     |
|Arsenal                 |3     |
|Schalke 04              |2     |
|SC Freiburg             |1     |
|Hannover 96             |1     |
|Lazio                   |1     |
|Chelsea                 |1     |
|Borussia Mönchengladbach|1     |
|Real Madrid             |1     |
+------------------------+------+

scala> df1.write.format("json").save(<path of parent json dir>)
```

Comment: Isn't it overkill to use spark for that?  I mean, if OP has an Array[String] in memory, why can't he use a third party lib to write to json?

Comment: Your third party tool will not be able to handle parallelism and immutability like dataframe. Suppose you have large amount of data then how you will distribute across cluster?

Comment: Apparently, he already has an Array[String] in memory, I might be wrong, but the overhead should not be that much, is it?

Comment: If you want to use spark then you should use Spark utility. And for overhead  it depends on data not logic. Data size will be same in both case either you keep in Array of String or Dataframe . Yes you  can use third party tool but  it will also take same time then there is no harm to use Spark utility if you are using spark framework. I suspect he has provided us sample data and logic.. but might  want to work with large data and just wanted to know logic in spark so I have choose  spark utility over third party and some times third party tool does not give us correct results in distributive